# Adding polylines using leaflet with array information included

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm very much a beginner with both Javascript and Leaflet so apologies if this is an easy fix, or I get some terminology incorrect...

I'm looking to draw polylines using leaflet from a csv (which I've brought in and parsed using Papaparse). Whilst I can draw very basic versions of these, I am unable to pass over any of the attributes from the csv (for example each link includes attributes relating to traffic flow which I would ideally like to symbolise.

My array is as follows:
[image]

Within which I have objects which look as follows (where display_links is the array with all my information) image:
[image]

```
function showlinks(display_links) {

    display_links.forEach(function (item, index) {
        Origin = new L.LatLng(item.Lat1, item.Lng1);
        Dest = new L.LatLng(item.Lat2, item.Lng2);
        polylinePoints = [Origin, Dest]
        pLatLngs.push(polylinePoints)
    });

    var polylineOptions = {
    color: 'black',
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 0.9
    };

    polyline = new L.Polyline(pLatLngs, polylineOptions);
    map.addLayer(polyline);
};
```

There is probably a more efficient way of doing this entire task (and my inexperience with arrays and objects wont be helping), but I basically created a new array of only lat long values which could be read by leaflet. However, when I tried to have a larger more detailed array with both lat, long, ID and Total_Flow the code wouldn't run.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, I've been going round in circles for days now and just getting nowhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like you are doing either premature optimization (by trying to draw everything in just one polyline) or naïve thinking about your data structure (assuming that the segments are always correlative). You will run into problems as soon as two segments are not correlative, or as soon as two correlative segments have different attributes e.g. different `Traffic_Flow`.

So the canonical approach for a minimally viable program would be to draw one `L.Polyline` per pair of points:

```
display_links.forEach(function (item, index) {
    var origin = new L.LatLng(item.Lat1, item.Lng1);
    var dest = new L.LatLng(item.Lat2, item.Lng2);

    L.polyline([origin, dest]).addTo(map);
});
```

While optionally using some other attribute from each row to control the styling of the `L.Polyline` via [its options](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#polyline-option), e.g.:

```
display_links.forEach(function (item, index) {
    var origin = new L.LatLng(item.Lat1, item.Lng1);
    var dest = new L.LatLng(item.Lat2, item.Lng2);

    var color:
    if (item.TotalFlow > 100) {
       color = 'red';
    } else {
       color = 'green';
    }

    L.polyline([origin, dest], { color: color }).addTo(map);
});
```

Or a shorter form like

```
L.polyline([origin, dest], { color: item.TotalFlow > 100 ? 'red' : 'green' }).addTo(map);
```

I would encourage you to **not** aim for an efficient processing of the data. On one hand, you are dealing with only 18 segments - on the other, it would involve having the data in [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) form, and then perform an [edge contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_contraction) on nodes that only have two segments which share all their attributes. Instead, ask for the original data in a format more suited to the task, e.g. GeoJSON.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! What is bad about dealing with it in graph form? We will have networks of about 2000/3000 links and our networks are usually in this format so I would be surprised if I can get anything in a different format...

Comment: Dealing with graph data is just cumbersome and prone to bugs (specially if you're a JS newbie). If the each of the 2000-3000 links/segments have different attributes, do one `L.Polyline` for segment. Otherwise, you should be able to reach somebody who should help you get the data in some well-known GIS format.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll discuss with the team we get the data from about putting this into a different format for ease. I will accept your answer and for now work with the solution provided.